# Opacity in TikZ, ruins whole structure in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, transparency

I am making a presentation in beamer. I wanted to make a `TikZ` picture and change it's opacity, locally on specific items. When I did, the structure color changed...

[image]

I will attach my preable as well as the frame that does the damage...

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{kerkis}
\mode<presentation>
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\setbeamercovered{higly dynamic}
\usetheme[watermark=ntua-logo.jpg]{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top

\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\title[SRS/APV readout with mmDAQ/Recomm\hspace{1.5cm} Stony Brook, NYC]{rd51 mm     tracker \& SRS/APV readout using mmDAQ/Recomm}
\author[Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios\hspace{2.5cm}{athanasios.stamatopoulos@cern.ch}]    {Stamatopoulos N. Athanasios}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%------------------tikz------------------------

\usetikzlibrary{%
calc,%
fadings,%
shadings%
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\transdissolve
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[->,color=red,thick](4,0) -- (-4,0);
\draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (3.5,2) rectangle (2.5,-2);%When applying opacity tha whole structure color is changed
\draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (2,2) rectangle (1,-2);
\draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (0.5,2) rectangle (-0.5,-2);
\draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (-1,2) rectangle (-2,-2);
\draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (-2.5,2) rectangle (-3.5,-2);

\draw[color=red] node at (5,0.5) {\footnotesize Beam};
\draw node at (3,-2.5) {\footnotesize mm2};
\draw node at (1.5,-2.5) {\footnotesize mm3};
\draw node at (0,-2.5) {\footnotesize mm4};
\draw node at (0,-3) {\footnotesize mm7};
\draw node at (-1.5,-2.5) {\footnotesize mm5};
\draw node at (-3,-2.5) {\footnotesize mm6};

\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hspace{1cm}
\end{column}%

\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\end{column}%
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I changed a bit the code(again) so as to be a really MWE

Before opacity

[image]

After opacity

[image]

Can you see the difference now?

When I apply opacity in the `tikz` picture the whole structure color changes! Before `opacity` it is alive and then it goes too pale...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please cut down your code a little bit, it is hardly *minimal*!  When I compile it, as well as missing various pictures, I have no idea what the problem is: it bears no relation to the sample images that you have posted, and even in those them I'm not all that clear what aspect has changed.  Please try to find a smaller example that demonstrates the problem, that'll make it easier to find an answer.

Comment: Still not minimal.  There's still the `\includegraphics` commands - are they necessary?  If so, you'll have to provide the files.  And, no, I can't see the difference.  Which bit of the picture am I meant to be looking at?

Comment: I've just tried your code again (you'd commented out `\begin{document}` by the way!) and I still don't see what I'm meant to be looking at.  Could you please edit it, removing (not just commenting) all the unnecessary stuff, and mark what bit is causing the problem.  A good thing to do (if possible) is put a comment before a particular line saying "Works without the next line" because then it is clear to someone trying what specifically to look for.

Comment: It is now edited!I hope it is better now! Sorry for any confusion...!

Comment: Still rather large!  Anyway, when I compile the document then I get no change in the title page.  I tried putting `\end{document}` right after the title frame to cut off all the tikz stuff and there was no difference in the title page before and after.  I'm beginning to suspect it might be due to your PDF viewer, or an old package of beamer.  Try reducing your example even more.  What do you need to add to `\documentclass{beamer}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\begin{frame}\tikz\draw[opacity=.5] (0,0) -- (1,0);\end{frame}\end{document}` to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried in a friends PC and I cannot see any difference, indeed... So it is too localised...I really hate my system...I suggest to close the question as too localised. I am so sorry for the whole mess...But I truly see some difference on my system!

Comment: AFAIK there is some issue with AR, if transparency is involved, then AR or other PDF viewers might change the way, how colors are processed internally.

Answer (score 0):

I see no change (with both Acrobat X and SumatraPDF) before and after I remove all the unnecessary code that might be interfering.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe,tikz,lmodern}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %<- Instead of snakes library which is obsolete

\title[My short title although it looks longer \hspace{1cm} than my long title]{My longer and longer title}
\author[My name\hspace{2.5cm}{my@email.com}]{My name}
\institute{NTUA/CERN}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
        \draw[->,color=red,thick](0,0) -- (-4,0);
        \draw[yellow!60,fill,rounded corners,opacity=0.9] (-1,2) rectangle (-2,-2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I should register that I'm using xpdf on Mac OS X (Lion) with TeXLive 2012 and I see no difference.

Comment: Really? But you see it for yourself... The color is not the same. Before using `opacity` color is alive...

Comment: @Thanos I think (but not sure) your PDF viewer cannot handle transparencies and other recent additions on the PDF specifications. Does it happen also with `article` documentclass instead of beamer?