# TikZ: transparency causes problems with the color black (opacity, transparency, color model, Adobe Reader)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, adobe

I want to have a fill color with transparency but I also want the text to be perfectly opaque. But somehow it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[myStack/.style={
  rectangle split, 
  rectangle split parts=3, 
  draw, 
  fill=yellow,
  fill opacity = 0.6,
  text=black,
  text opacity = 1,
  }]

\node [myStack]{
                abc
\nodepart{two}  bde
\nodepart{three}cfg
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When I zoom in (Adobe Reader) then I also see that even the black border is not really black and rather dark gray.

Can somebody reproduce the problem?

**Update**

After I updated MiKTeX the problem was kind of solved. However black still is rather dark gray. After opening the PDF with Adobe Professional I figured out that when I change the color profile then black is black again. See the screenshots (in German):

Problem: Black is gray

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Problem solved:

[image]

Can anyone reproduce that black is not black?

PS: I think it's related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74841/opacity-in-tikz-ruins-whole-structure-in-beamer) question.

**Problem Solved**

Apparently [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat) questions address the same problem. Adding

```
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

before `\begin{document}` solved the problem. According to [Martin Heller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem) "this makes Adobe Reader use the RGB rendering model for pages with transparency". Still I don't get it fully...

Comment: Your mwe perfectly work to me. Fill is yellow with given transparency and do not interfere with text opacity, i.e. text is black. I check in Sumatra as well in Adobe Reader. Regarding your definition of "myStack" the line "fill=yellow" is superfluous, it is sufficient to declary just "fill opacity=0.6".

Comment: Hi. But I have to declare a color. How could this be superfluous?

Comment: You have right. I mismatch text color width fill color. If you like to have black text, it is not necessary to define text color. Sorry for my mismatch.

Comment: @dr In A(R)-DC this doesn't seem an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Fillopacity will affect the text, if you want a "transparent" color, and a black text do yellow!60 instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[myStack/.style={
  rectangle split, 
  rectangle split parts=3, 
  draw, 
  fill=yellow!60,
  %fill opacity = 0.6,
  }]

\node [myStack]{
                abc
\nodepart{two}  bde
\nodepart{three}cfg
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the ! mean?

Comment: Try yellow!10, yellow!50, yellow!10!red, it is a melting between first and second color : 10% red 90% yellow. See xcolor manual

Comment: But this doesn't really explain why the OP is getting the strange output he describes in his question. The original code should work as expected (in fact, it does on my system), so perhaps is just a matter of updating packages?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: on my system line are black and the three texts are gray. If put only fill opacity=0.6, with no fill color the text is gray too. I have installed pfg 3.0. Witch packages should be updated ?

Comment: In my real usage I have a background and therefore I need real transparency. I will try to update tomorrow. Thanks so far.

Comment: fill opacity and text are on different places and they don't interfere if there are no viewer issues.